# Smooth surfaces appearing as an anticanonical section

Tags: algebraic-geometry

(This is a very naïve question.)

Work over $\mathbb{C}$. We say a smooth algebraic surface $S$ is a section if there is a smooth projective $3$-fold $X$ and $0 \neq F \in H^{0}(X,-K_{X})$, with $S = \{F=0\} \subset X$.

Is this class of algebraic surfaces classified? Are there some easy restrictions on $S$?

Comment: The simplest case is quartics in $\mathbb P^3$, which are K3 surfaces. The case would be anticanonical divisors on quartic threefolds; by adjunction, these are hyperplane sections, hence again quartic surfaces. Basically you are asking "what can the polarization of a Fano threefold look like?" The literature on Fano threefolds is pretty big (I think there are 88 families of them) but I think solved for the most part, so you might want to just look at the classification thereof. If you're lucky they will have identified the polarizations; otherwise you might have a lot of computing to do.

Comment: A $3$-fold with $H^{0}(X,-K_{X}) \neq 0$ is not necessarily Fano. I am aware that for fano $3$-folds any anticanonical section in a $K3$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2782435/anticanonical-sections-of-fano-3-fold for a proof).

Comment: Ah, nice. Smacking myself in the forehead now. What are some simple non-Fano examples here, if I may ask?

Comment: I don't know too many, but there is a class of variety called "weak Fanos", where $-K_{X}$ is big and nef, but not necessarily ample. A big and nef line bundle always has sections. Here is a $2$-dimensional example, if you blow up $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ in $3$ colinear points then that is a weak Fano, but not Fano since the $3$ points are not in general position. There are many more examples in dimension $3$, see some of the papers about classification of weak Fano $3$-folds.